# How can I level up?

Tags: ultima-5-lazarus

What do I need to do to level up in Ultima 5: Lazarus?  I have tried sleeping in beds and outdoor in a bedroll over 5 times but have not seen Lord British in a dream. I have over 1000 experience points but have not leveled up.

Is there also a list of how many points are needed for each level? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be helpful:

> Since Lord British was kidnapped, level advancement is a little difficult in Ultima V. After acquiring the needed experience points (see Ultima IV), the party has to hole up and camp for the maximum # of hours. Now a little luck is needed for the spirit of Lord British to appear and grant any earned levels. Starting with this installment, characters gain 30 HP with each new level.
>
> Stats are also given by Lord British during leveling up, although they are chosen rather randomly. Stats are also granted by the shrines after fulfilling the quest given by the shrine (reading the Codex of Ultimate Wisdom).

Also, you can reach level 8 and that's as far as you can go!

Source: [wiki](http://ultima.wikia.com/wiki/Character_Advancement)

Answer (score 1):

The maximum is level 8.

If you want stats gain, there are 2 ways:

a) Stats are also granted by the shrines after fulfilling the quest given by the shrine

b) Stats are also given by Lord British during leveling up, although they are chosen rather randomly

Note: 
The Shrine of Humility does not give any stats increase.
The best shrine is Shrine of Sacrifice or Shrine of Spirituality, since that has Str, Dex, Int increase.

Sources:

http://ultima.wikia.com/wiki/Character_Advancement

http://gigi.nullneuron.net/ultima/u5/u5quests.php